# UserPrincipal Only Returns Logged in User

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I am working on a project that will hopefully allow a single click user creation across Active Directory, and some other applications that we use.

I am working with the

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
```

Namespace and the

```
UserPrinciple
```

Object

The problem that I am having is it will only return the logged in user even when I pass another user into the method

Here is some code

For adding a user to a new group

```
public bool AddUserToGroup(string sUserName, string sGroupName)
        {
            try
            {
                UserPrincipal oUserPrincipal = GetUser(sUserName);
                Trace.WriteLine(oUserPrincipal.Context);
                GroupPrincipal oGroupPrincipal = GetGroup(sGroupName);
                if (oGroupPrincipal != null)
                {
                    if (!IsUserGroupMember(sUserName, sGroupName))
                    {
                        oGroupPrincipal.Members.Add(pp);
                        oGroupPrincipal.Save();
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Here is the GetUser()

```
UserPrincipal oUserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(oPrincipalContext, sUserName);
            return oUserPrincipal;
```

But it only returns the logged in user.

Let me know if you need any more information...

I look forward to some replies :)

Martyn

Edit PrincipalContext Method

```
PrincipalContext oPrincipalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, sDomain, sDefaultOU, ContextOptions.SimpleBind, sServiceUser, sServicePassword);
            return oPrincipalContext;
```

Comment: Can you share the code where you instantiate `oPrincipalContext`?

Comment: Updated my main question

Answer (score 0):

I have found that you must pass the account type through to the GetUser method

So originally it was

```
UserPrincipal oUserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(oPrincipalContext, sUserName);
            return oUserPrincipal;
```

Now it is like this

```
UserPrincipal oUserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(oPrincipalContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, sUserName);
        return oUserPrincipal;
```

If you dont specify the

```
IdentityType.SamAccountName
```

It will look locally

Martyn